# splash (/scrapinghub) - wait = max 10

Tags: python, splash-screen, scrapinghub

I am using scrapinghubs splash for rendering javascript pages. It is really a great tool, but I don't understand why the maximum value for wait is 10. Is there a possibility to set higher values?

Thank you very much.

Best regards,
Julian

Answer (score 0):

You can use [splash:wait](http://splash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripting-ref.html#splash-wait) - it doesn't have 10s limit. Check this tutorial on Splash Lua scripts: http://splash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripting-tutorial.html.

Unfortunately, currently there is no way to override 'wait' max value for endpoints other than `/execute`. All other endpoints can be implemented as an `/execute` Lua script, but making it possible to configure limits still would be nice. See also - https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/141.